# How to get Controller name, and data available in a custom Controller using GetApiExplorer()

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

Hi I have `BaseController : ApiController`

And `TestController : BaseController`

How to get Controller Name & and relevant details of **TestController**

using bellow code

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions
    .GroupBy(x => x.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName)
    .Select(x => x.First().ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName)
```

I can able to get details (**ApiDescriptions**) of `BaseController`

How to get details (**ApiDescriptions**) of **TestController** ?

Comment: What are the "details" you're referring to?

Comment: @von v : `ApiDescriptions`

Answer (score 0):

**My Mistake**

Now I comment bellow code from `TestController`. And now Everything work perfectly

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```